# Sentence transformation with "say"

Tags: sentence, paraphrasing

In an exercise, a sentence is given:

> I think it would be best if you didn't mention John's behaviour to his mother.

The task is to write a second sentence that has exactly the same meaning, using between 2 and 8 words inserted into a given template:

> I don't think you ... John's behaviour to his mother.

An additional requirement is that the word **say** in exactly this form must be included.

Can someone please help?

Comment: What have you tried? If you need to use *say,* how about expressing the second sentence as "I don't think you \_\_\_ say..." That will give you an answer, although I think the sentence as given has other difficulties: the obvious way of expressing it (a) requires a preposition as well and (b) is really colloquial.

Comment: I didnt come up with anything that has the same meaning. "I don't think you had to say about John's behaviour to his mother" seems to be too 'strict' also i am not sure if 'say about sth to sb' is correct.  I may be wrong but 'tell about sth to sb' seems to be more correcr in my opinion

Comment: @Andrew Leach: the obvious way that I thought of isn't colloquial (although it does require a preposition and the word *anything*).

Comment: As i wrote you can use between 3 and 8 words so prepositions and anything are fine.

Comment: 'I don't think you should say anything about John's behaviour to his mother' is totally idiomatic. But what do _you_ suggest? // I've left the title as I suspect this is what  British Council tests use, but I'd not consider 'paraphrase' to be synonymous with 'transform/ation'.

Comment: @Edwin correct me if im wrong but i dont think if this has the same meaning as the given sentence.  Given sentence suggests that  someone has already mentioned john's behaviour to his mother.  And the sentence you gave means that it is strongly recommenden no to tell john's mother about his behaviour. Am i wrong?

Comment: As with all synonyms (and the term covers words, phrases, ... sentences) interchangeability in all wider contexts with absolutely no change even in connotation is impossible. I'd wager that this is the closest possible with the constraints given. // If you want to be taken as a serious English student, you need to address basic mistakes. There are at least 8 _different_ mistakes (counting the non-capitalised _John_'s as one, etc) in your last comment. ELL is for people mastering the basics.

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll try to take your advice to heart.